What is the full symmetry group of a tile in the shape of a regular n–gon?
I am trying to answer the question on exercise 4.5.6 from the book "Algebra: Abstract and concrete" by Goodman. The chapter is on the symmetries of polyhedra and in this exercise he asks me to characterize the full symmetry group of a tile in the shape of a regular n–gon, which is just a thickened version of a two-dimensional n-gon.
In the preceding problems I used the inversion (-E) to show that the full symmetry group of the brick and the square tile are isomorphic to $K_4 \times Z_2$ and $D_4 \times Z_2$ (note that in this book $D_4$ has order 8) respectively. I noticed that if n is even then the inversion belongs to the group of symmetries and so I can use a similar argument as with the brick and square tile to show that $G\cong R\times Z_2 \cong D_n\times Z_2$, where $R$ is the subgroup of rotational symmetries, which is normal because it has index 2. However, if n is odd then $-E\notin G$ and so my previous argument won't apply.
I have been trying to work the FSG of the pentagon-like tile, with limited success, just to see if I can spot a clue that helps me solve the problem for the general case. Although I suspect that in this case $G\cong D_{10}$, because the latter is the only group of order 20 with at least 10 elements of order 2, I still can't explain how the symmetries of the 10-gon would be related to those of the 5-gon tile.
Any help or hint on this problem would be highly appreciated.
